# Reset in Shiny applications

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to clear what ever is written in the text area but looks like it not working. Based on the below applications, when the user clicks on "click" button, the contents (if written) should get cleared. But it is not. Can anyone help me here please........................................

```
data(mtcars)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic sidebar"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(id = "menu", sidebarMenuOutput("menu"))),
  dashboardBody(tabItems
                (
                  tabItem
                  (tabName = "plots", h2("Dashboard plots"),
                    fluidRow(column(width = 12, class = "well",
                                    h4("Boxplot"),
                                    plotOutput("bxp")))
                  ),
                  tabItem(tabName = "dashboard", h2("Dashboard tab content"),
                          dataTableOutput(outputId = "subdt"),textAreaInput("sd","label1"),textAreaInput("sd1","label2") ,
                          actionButton("idff","click"))
                )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$menu <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(
      # menuItem("Plots Menu", tabName = "plots", icon = icon("line-chart")),
      menuItem("Table Menu", icon = icon("info"),
               menuSubItem(
                 "Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("calendar")
               ),
               selectInput(
                 inputId = "mcm", label = "Some label", multiple = TRUE,
                 choices = unique(mtcars$cyl), selected = unique(mtcars$cyl)
               )
      )
    )
  })
  
  observe({
    print(input$menu)
  })
  datsub <- reactive({
    mtcars %>%
      filter_at(vars("cyl"), all_vars(. %in% input$mcm))
  })
  
  output$subdt <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(datsub(),selection = if(input$menu == "dashboard"){'single'} else {'none'})
    # print(datatable.selection())
  })
  
  # datatable(datsub(),selection = if(input$menu == "dashboard"){'single'} else {'none'})
  output$bxp <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(100))
  }) 
  
  observeEvent(input$idff,{
    print("cjec")
    shinyjs::reset('sd')
    shinyjs::reset('sd1')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You could use `updateTextAreaInput` with `value = ""`.

Comment: You might want to use `useShinyjs()` on the `ui` side, if you are going to use shinyjs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to update the `textAreaInput` as suggested in the comments. Update the event handler as follows:

```r
observeEvent(input$idff, {
    updateTextAreaInput(session = session, inputId = 'sd', value = "")
    updateTextAreaInput(session = session, inputId = 'sd1', value = "")
})
```